# CDO VBS Script for office 365 not working

Tags: vbscript, cdo.message

I modified a VBS script to send authenticated email through my office 365 account, but cannot get it to work.  I get the error: `sendemail365.vbs(17, 2) (null): The server rejected the sender address.`

The server response was:

```
530 5.7.57 SMTP; Client was not aut
henticated to send anonymous mail during MAIL FROM [DM5PR06CA0041.namprd06.prod.
outlook.com].
```

I can connect using the email address in thunderbird and send emails authenticated.  Any suggestions what I need to tweak?  Everything I research seems to be very old and does not work.

```
   Set objEmail      = CreateObject("CDO.Message")
 objEmail.From     = "dummy@dummy.com"
 objEmail.To = "sendto@testing.net"
 objEmail.Subject  = "Testing office 365 Subject"
 objEmail.Textbody = "Testing office 365 body"
 with objEmail.Configuration.Fields
  .Item ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusing")        = 2
  .Item ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserver")       = "smtp-mail.outlook.com"
  .Item ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserverport")   = 587
  .Item ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpauthenticate") = 1
  .Item ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusername")     = "dummy@dummycom"
  .Item ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendpassword")     = "password(actualpassword)"
  .Item ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendtls")          = True
  .Item ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpconnectiontimeout") = 10
  .Update
 end with
 objEmail.Send
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here stems from your e-mail provider rather than anything to do with your code. See this post from Microsoft about [direct sends](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_outlook-mso_winother-mso_o365b/client-was-not-authenticated-to-send-anonymous/d405bcb0-f40c-42fa-b1b2-477597100123)...

> This indicates that you are connecting to the SMTP client submission
>   endpoint (smtp.office365.com), which can't be used for direct send.
>   For direct send, use the MX endpoint for your Office 365 tenant, which
>   ends with "mail.protection.outlook.com." So, please let your admin
>   check the MX record. Moreover, please check if the SMTP port is
>   25/TLS.